# Django syncdb and migrate

Tags: django, django-south, syncdb

I'm moving django website from one server to another, and I tried to syncdb, so i've put `python manage.py syncdb`, and i get this output:

```
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

    orders | ordercontact

Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.

    Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: no
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
No fixtures found.

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.admin
 > django.contrib.admindocs
 > django.contrib.markup
 > django.contrib.sitemaps
 > django.contrib.redirects
 > django_filters
 > freetext
 > sorl.thumbnail
 > django_extensions
 > south
 > currencies
 > pagination
 > tagging
 > honeypot
 > core
 > faq
 > logentry
 > menus
 > news
 > shop
 > shop.cart
 > shop.orders

Not synced (use migrations):
 - dbtemplates
 - contactform
 - links
 - media
 - pages
 - popularity
 - testimonials
 - shop.brands
 - shop.collections
 - shop.discount
 - shop.pricing
 - shop.product_types
 - shop.products
 - shop.shipping
 - shop.tax
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

Next step was `python manage.py migrate`, and this is what I've got:

```
Running migrations for dbtemplates:
 - Migrating forwards to 0002_auto__del_unique_template_name.
 > dbtemplates:0001_initial
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

! You *might* be able to recover with:   = DROP TABLE `django_template` CASCADE; []
   = DROP TABLE `django_template_sites` CASCADE; []

 ! The South developers regret this has happened, and would
 ! like to gently persuade you to consider a slightly
 ! easier-to-deal-with DBMS.
 ! NOTE: The error which caused the migration to fail is further up.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 105, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/south/migration/__init__.py", line 191, in migrate_app
    success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 221, in migrate_many
    result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, database)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 292, in migrate_many
    result = self.migrate(migration, database)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 125, in migrate
    result = self.run(migration)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 99, in run
    return self.run_migration(migration)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 81, in run_migration
    migration_function()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/south/migration/migrators.py", line 57, in <lambda>
    return (lambda: direction(orm))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_dbtemplates-1.3-py2.6.egg/dbtemplates/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 18, in forwards
    ('last_changed', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField')(default=datetime.datetime.now)),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/south/db/generic.py", line 226, in create_table
    ', '.join([col for col in columns if col]),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/south/db/generic.py", line 150, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 34, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 86, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'django_template' already exists")
```

My question is do I need to remove tables `django_template` and `django_template_sites` from MySQL? Both tables are empty.

I'm running on CentOS 6, django 1.3.1, python 2.6

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try

```
syncdb --all
```

as I have the same problem and --all just works.

I found this solution here https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1343

Answer (score 15):

This might help others going through the same issue.

Since your database is to be created now and there are no migrations needed, after doing what Ahmad mentioned, also do a fake migration so south will mark all migration scripts as already run.  In short, run these.

```
syncdb --all
migrate --fake
```

Please note that if you already have data in your database you shouldn't use syncdb --all.

Answer (score 6):

```
$python manage.py syncdb --migrate
```

this migrates what has to be migrated

*worked for me (django 1.4)*

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is mark that first migration as done:

```
./manage.py migrate dbtemplates --fake 0001
```

It seems to be that you already have in your database the schema that you want to create.

Comment: That didnt help, nothing has changed. I run your command, and again `python manage.py syncdb` and output is the same.