# How to do django syncdb in version 1.4.2?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-syncdb

How to do syncdb in django 1.4.2?
i.e. having data in database, how to load the models again when the data schema is updated?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you already have data in the database and have made changes to the models and want to update the database schema according to your changes in models while still keeping the data, you'll need to look into south migrations (https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: The newer versions of django have the south module integrated by default. For your version of django, you'd need to install the south module and put it in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Django 1.4 does support migrations. I had this source to verify, will have to download the version and check it again because the docs are not giving much info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834237/django-syncdb-and-migrate

Comment: @ArpitGoyal Look at the django migrations documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/. The documentation is available for django > 1.7 as south was officially included in django in version 1.7

Comment: @ArpitGoyal South has de-facto been a part of Django for a long time, but it was a separate package. 1.7 introduced a brand new migration system into Django core.

Comment: @Amyth "...have the south module integrated" is - I'm nitpicking here - not exactly true. The migration system in 1.7 has been made from scratch by Andrew Godwin, the creator of South. Though it was inspired by his previous work on South, it is very different in many aspects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Amyth for the hints. 
btw the commands is a bit different, i will post a 10x tested result here.

Using south 
1. setup the model

`python manage.py schemamigration models --initial`

2. dump data if you have to

`python manage.py dumpdata -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission --natural > data.json`

3. syncdb

`python manage.py syncdb`
`python manage.py migrate models`

4. load the data back into the db

`python manage.py loaddata data.json`

5. Afterwards, you may use

`python manage.py schemamigration models --auto`
`python manage.py migrate models`

after every change you made in the models schema

A few notes 
1. Unloading the database and reload it is essential, because if not doing so the first migration will tell you already have those models. 
2. The `-e contenttypes -e auth.Permission --natural` parameter in `dumpdata` is essential otherwise exception will be thrown when doing loaddata.

Answer (score 6):

As you're using an older version of `django` you'll need to install the [`South`](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) module and make migrations for your apps.

To install South, you can use `pip` or `easy_install`

```
pip install South
```

Once you have the south module installed put it in your django projects settings' `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
"south"
)
```

Then you'll need to make initial migrations first for your apps. So for an app named `example` you can run the command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations example --initial
python manage.py migrate
```

After the initial migration creation you make changes to your models and then make the new migrations and apply them.

```
python manage.py makemigrations example --auto
python manage.py migrate
```